# Nexus & Maven Corporate Pom - What should it contain?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, nexus

We are currently evaluating to establish an internal company nexus repository for our java development.

Unfortunately there are still some questions unanswered, but maybe you can help.

A parent pom for all projects inside the company seems to be best practice. What is not clear is what this pom should contain, besides the `<organization>`section.

Is it best practice to also specify the `<distributionManagement>` inside this pom? If yes, what should it contain and what should it look like if we want to reference the company nexus (`<site>`, `<repository>`, `<snapshotRepository>`) ?

How to handle the fact that (according to sonatype) it is best practice that each project has its own repository without the need to specify the nexus root path in each pom?

Should we specify also the `<repositories>` and `<pluginRepositories>` section there (referencing our internal nexus)?

Additionally we want that basically each project can deploy it's own site, could we specify this also inside the parent pom? And if yes, what should the site plugin configuration look like?

The best would be if someone could provide a full, examplary corporate pom that can be used with an internal nexus repository.

Or is it even better to put this stuff inside the `settings.xml` to not bind the project to a certain repository? But as far as I know the `<distributionManagement>` can't be specified inside the settings.xml? Also this will be a tedious work to update if the nexus url changes someday?

I am really confused about this whole stuff, eventhough I tried to read a lot about it.

Thank you in advance!

---

### UPDATE/Solution

Thanks to [Michael-O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696632/michael-o)'s answer below I have the information I need.

1. `<repositories>` and `<pluginRepositories>` tag belong to the
   `settings.xml`. This is the place to specify the nexus repository
   for **"Downloading"** (optionally include credentials using `<servers>`
2. `<distributionManagement>` belongs to the corporate base pom,
   referencing a basic Nexus repository for releases and snapshots. This is the place to specify the nexus repository for **"Uploading"** (deploying).
3. If sub-repositories (for logically grouping projects) are needed, they are specified inside the projects `pom.xml` and therefore override the ones inside the company pom. To simplify this and for keeping the basic nexus url only inside the corporate pom (beware of url changes) it might be useful/possible to specify the repositories inside `<distributionManagement>` in the following manner:

   ```
   <repository>
     <id>company-repository</id>
     <name>Internal Releases</name>
     <url>http://my.nexus.repo/releases/${subRepositoryId}-releases</url>
   </repository>
   ```
4. An exemplary corporate pom can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33522751/1342006)
5. To prevent configuration changes inside the pom files or settings one could use an alias for the nexus url. Though this would mean additional effort from the administrative side.
6. If a site for a project is needed no general definition inside the corporate pom can be used, it has to be declared individually for each project pom. To simplify this process the site nexus url could be stored inside a property of the corporate pom that can then be referenced inside the site distribution management of the project poms.

The corporate pom could contain something similar to this:

```
  <project>
    ....
    <properties>
      <repository.group>common</repository.group>
      <repository.url.base>http://my.nexus:port/nexus/content</repository.url.base>
      <repository.url.repositories>${repository.url.base}/repositories</repository.url.repositories>
      <repository.url.sites>${repository.url.base}/sites</repository.url.sites>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
        <id>company-repository</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>${repository.url.repositories}/${repository.group}-releases</url>
      </repository>
      <snapshotRepository>
        <id>company-repository</id>
        <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
        <url>${repository.url.repositories}/${repository.group}-snapshots</url>
      </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    ....
  </project>
```

The project pom similiar to this:

```
  <project>
    ...
    <properties>
      <repository.group>project-group</repository.group>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
      <site>
        <id>company-repository</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>dav:${repository.url.sites}/project-site</url>
      </site>
    </distributionManagement>
    ...
  </project>
```

---

**WARNING:** One might wonder why to not directly include the site part into the corporate pom. This is not possible, as you can't deploy multiple sites to the same site repository without creating a mess. Using the way above one does not need to create a repository for each project, but is able to group them logically together into larger groups or leave them in the common-releases/snapshots group/repository.

Comment: The repositories which will be used should be put into settings.xml (which results in using the corporate nexus)...The distributionManagement should be put into corpoprate pom file (best is to use some properties for the url) which can be overritten simply in your CI server...

Comment: Thanks already for the comment. For the local development I would put the properties inside a profile inside the `settings.xml` then?

Comment: @user1342006 Please see my edit regarding sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at the Apache Parent POM or the Maven Parent POM. A minimal corporate POM should look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>Exmaple Parent POM</name>
  <organization>
    <name>Example Inc.</name>
  </organization>

  <!-- This marked as deprecated for Maven 3.x. This is checked by maven-enforcer-plugin -->
  <!-- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5297 -->
  <prerequisites>
    <maven>${maven.version}</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://example.com/repos/svn/ExmapleJava/example-parent/trunk/</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://example.com/repos/svn/ExmapleJava/example-parent/trunk/</developerConnection>
    <url>https://example.com/repos/websvn/browse/ExmapleJava/example-parent/trunk/</url>
  </scm>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>nexus-example</id>
      <name>Nexus Exmaple Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://example.com/nexus/content/repositories/example-releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>nexus-example</id>
      <name>Nexus Exmaple Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>https://example.com/nexus/content/repositories/example-snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <properties>
    <maven.version>3.2</maven.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <surefire.version>2.19</surefire.version>
    <javadoc.version>2.10.3</javadoc.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
          <configuration>
            <excludeResources>true</excludeResources>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <mavenExecutorId>forked-path</mavenExecutorId>
            <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
            <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
            <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${javadoc.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <quiet>true</quiet>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${surefire.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.10</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.4</version>
          <configuration>
            <buildNumberPropertyName>buildRevision</buildNumberPropertyName>
            <timestampPropertyName>buildTimestamp</timestampPropertyName>
            <scmBranchPropertyName>buildScmBranch</scmBranchPropertyName>
            <revisionOnScmFailure>non-SCM</revisionOnScmFailure>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.10</version>
          <configuration>
            <includeConfigurationDirectoryInClasspath>false</includeConfigurationDirectoryInClasspath>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.8</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-maven</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireMavenVersion>
                  <version>${maven.version}</version>
                  <message>This project requires at least Maven ${maven.version}</message>
                </requireMavenVersion>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>example-release</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-sources</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

The plugins of course should vary for your company but this gets you started. This is actually our parent just removed our local information.

There is no information for the site deployment because we don't use it. Set it if you use it.

At *no* time your POM should contain `<repositories>` and `<pluginRepositories>` because this is bad practice. Ideally, your work with a repo group in Nexus mirroring (in `settings.xml`) all of your requests.

Inherit from and be happy.

How to handle sites:
Generally, each project has its own site and should be overridden in the dist mngt section. This is different to the artifacts. Whether your will host on Nexus or on a webserver like Apache is up to you. The bottom line is that every project site needs its distinct URL.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, this already helps! But there is still one point I can't seem to get working using this approach. If I now have an actual child project inheriting from this pom, it will be released into the `example-releases` repository. How do I handle the fact that different projects should get their own repositories? (https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/best.html - repositories per project/team) Or would you suggest the "Partition shared repositories"? And whats the point of including the `<distributionMgmt>` but not `<repositories>`? Isnt this also bad then?

Comment: @user1342006 We do also have this usecase and have rather chosen "Repositories Per Project/Team" better repo per production site. What you will ultimately do is leave the corpoporate POM as-is and override the distribution management information in your Project POM. You are done. You can always validat your POM with `mvn help:effective-pom`. It gives you the interpolated POM as Maven would see it.

Please keep in mind that if you use Nexus you have centralized user management, i.e., you can keep the server id always the same and refer to it in your `settings.xml`.

Comment: Not doing so would ultimately mean to duplicate credentials which is really annoying. See [MNG-5913](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5913).

Comment: Ok I think I mostly understand, thank you! But still, if I imagine having e.g. 50 different projects (just to exaggerate) that all override the ' `<distributionManagement`> section, and the nexus url changes, this would be a real worst case scenario. Would it be an idea to specify the base-url in the corporate pom followed by a property (e.g. `${project.uid})` that is then set inside the child poms? Would this work and make sense?

Comment: Regarding the chaning nexus url: Or would this be an IT problem then and we should just use an alias url to be sure... ?

Comment: If you plan to use exactly one repo for one project, that would be a mess (IMHO). I would reather logically group projects into one repo and work with target permissions in Nexus if you need them. Your approach `${project.uid}` makes sense and would actually work. Though, I have never tried this approach. At the end of the day, you should assess both options with your devs and admins and use the approach with the least amount of work. Ultimately, a few big repos might be a better solution and your Nexus admin will do the rest.

Comment: Aliasing URLs wih Apache webserver would either mean to work with redirects (time-consuming) or real location aliases but that would still be additional admin work.

Comment: You can update your question by sharing your preferred solution and I or others can share their thoghts.

Comment: does someone actually use only *one* corporate pom? we have inheritance structure of lots of poms, maybe about 17 when you consider all the dependency poms... each for different use cases.

Comment: @eis I think you're right and actually this is one of the next steps I wanted to evaluate. But first of all I needed the most basic pom/nexus structure to get started. The next steps will of course involve finding commonalities and providing different parent poms for different use cases (e.g. jee-application, desktop-application, etc.), whereas those again inherit from the base pom.

Comment: @user1342006 If you think my answer was helpful, consider upvoting/accepting it.